# How to create drop down Table view Using Two Custom Cell?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have two cell one for section and other one for row .

**This is my code**

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return arrname.count;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if(collapse==section)
    {
        return [arrDescription count]+1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }

}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

//    productCell =[[productScreenCell alloc]init];
    productCell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    productSub=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell1"];
if(indexPath.row==0)
{
    if(arrname.count>0)
    {
        NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:LocalImage@"%@",[arrimages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        productCell.lblCostProduct.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrcost objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
        productCell.imgProduct.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]]];
        productCell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"#232323"];
        productCell.lblProductScreen.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrname objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
        [productCell.btnClick addTarget:self action:@selector(touchup:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        productCell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
}
    else
    {
         productSub.lblSubProduct.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrDescription objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1]];
    }

//

        productCell.btnClick.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"#ffc400"];
        productCell.btnClick.tag=indexPath.row;
    return productCell;

}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  if (indexPath.row == 0 && collapse != indexPath.section) {
            collapse = (int)indexPath.section;
            [tableView reloadData];
        }
        else
        {

        }

    }
```

I have searched many drop down code snippet ,but everything is not clear or it should be third party program ,any don just give me simple drop down table list coding for me.

Answer (score 1):

Several issues here : first the 'proper' way to do it is to use the built-in functionality for section headers.  This method allows you to create and return a UIView that is used as the header for any sections in your tableview :

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

This means then that for numberOfRowsInSection, you just return a single value - the number of rows for that section, which I think you say is one.  You also have a numberOfSections method - which again you will return one for if there is only one section.

Then your cellForRowAtIndexPath method will just be concerned with setting up your single row, and the header will be setup in that viewForHeaderInSection method I mentioned.  Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: please if possible means send some code @luke Smith